# how to save null value in subsonic

Tags: subsonic

```
 Dim xbg As Rm

xbg.LobId = cmb_lob.SelectedValue
xbg.Mobile = mobno.Text
xbg.BusinessFax = faxno.Text
xbg.BusinessPhone = phno.Text
xbg.Save()
```

I have a combo box, which is not mandatory while input in the module. therefore user can select blank value in combo cox for which i want to save null in Oracle Database for that record. I had trid with following condition but fails to get result. you are requested to please help

```
if cmb_lob.selectedindex=-1 then 
    xbg.lob=dbnull 
else 
    xbg.LobId = cmb_lob.SelectedValue
```

Actual Problem arises when first user save record with selection in Combo box then user edit that record and select blank from Combo box. now i have to replace value of combox box with null at database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
if cmb_lob.selectedindex <> -1 then 
    xbg.LobId = cmb_lob.SelectedValue
else
    xbg.LobId = Nothing 'suggested by John Shean (see comments)
```

So that if the value is selected only then assign it to field else leave it as it is (null)

Comment: Actual Problem arises when first user save record with selection in Combo box then user edit that record and select blank from Combo box. now i have to replace value of combox box with null at database.

Comment: THANKS ONCE AGAIN BUT XBG.LOB IS NUMERIC TYPE WHEN I DO THE FOLLOWING XBG.LOBID=DBNULL.VALUE , GETTING EXCEPTION OF INVALID TYPE CAST.

Comment: Try xbg.LobId = Nothing instead

Answer (score 1):

Set it to null or whatever VB considers null - it will be set in the DB that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try xbg.LobId = Nothing instead – 
By John Sheehan